# Workflow to update library

Tags: workflow, update

I have two SharePoint libraries, library 1 is open to all users, library 2  has unique permissions.
Library 1 and library 2 should be identical, - so when a document is updated in library 1, i need it to automatically updates the same document in library 2. 
Has anyone created a workflow, for  a similar scenario?

Answer (score 0):

The approach has a fundamental problem. The workflow run on the current user context so If the logged in user don't have permission to the Library2 then it will fail.

Other than that the approach should work using below logic

1. Workflow should start of new/update event
2. Check if file exists on destination
3. If exists do an update list item action and update the fields
4. Else [copy to destination](https://cypher19.wordpress.com/workflow-copy-document-from-one-library-to-another/) and update list item

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try your suggestion


I was wondering if there was another approach.
What if all documents are stored within a specific folder in library 1, and the complete folder was copied to library 2 periodically.  
A requirement of this would be th the docs in library 2 would need to be overwritten to avoid duplication. 
Should have mentioned before, my experience of workflows is mainly using SP Designer, however I could use Nintex if required.

Comment: Creating a job is the best approach. There you will have access to the SharePoint Object Model which is much easier to implement.